# Python Monitor Website for changes

Tags: python, html, web, screen-scraping

I would like to login to a website, get the data, save it into a file, after some time get the new data and compare it with the old (saved) data and print if something has changed. How do I do that? The login is working, but the compare isn't. Why?

Thank you in advance!

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import time


def login():
    username = "username"
    password = "password"

    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login_username' : username, 'login_password' : password})
    opener.open('lol.com/login', login_data)
    resp = opener.open('lol.com/login')
    data = resp.read()
    print data    
    write_data(data)

def write_data(data):
    file = open("htmlString", "w")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    monitor(data)



def monitor(data):
    string1 = open("htmlString", "r").read()
    string2 = data
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        login()
        if string1 == string2:
            print "Nothing has changed"
        else:
            print "Something has changed"




login()
```

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? `monitor`, at best (I can't tell if your code gets that far), is only good for detecting one change. After that, it has nothing new to compare to because `data` is fixed.

Comment: It isn't even printing "Nothing has changed". Thats one problem. The second problem is that it's, as you said, only comparing one time. How can I fix this? I really don't know..

Comment: Well, those `print`s come in an `if`/`else` so your code doesn't make it that far. You need to debug earlier in the flow than that. If there's an error, you should put it in your question.

Comment: Do you get any printout at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your code quite tricky to follow. Here's an untested alternative that should get close to what you are trying to achieve.

```
def fetch_html():
    # fetch logic
    return html  # string

def write_html(html):  # string
    # write logic

def read_html():
    with open('page.html','r') as f:
        return f.read()

def monitor():
    write_html(fetch_html())
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        new_html = fetch_html()
        if new_html == read_html():
            print('Nothing has changed')
        else:
            print('Something has changed')
            write_html(new_html)

monitor()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `string2` isn't updated when you call `login()`. You should make `login()` return `data` and assign it to `string2` each loop.